how to Avoid download data on google colab temp disk and directly put it on mounted google drive
I was trying to participate on one of Kaggle competition which has data with size 313 gb.
I bought google Colab pro but it provided only 200gb, so I bought 2 tb from google drive and mount it with google Colab pro. but what is not expected that data should go first to temp disk space for colab before paste on drive!!!
I tried several ways to avoid that but no one of them worked or maybe I made them wrong.
I tried many way to avoid using temp disk space for storage:
1- try to let it stop when temp disk end and only use the downloaded data but gave corrupted zip file cannot be extracted.
2- thought that kaggle api that loaded on the temp disk may cause this, so I downloaded it on the drive, but the same thing.
3- try to use wget, hope it will not use temp but used it too
!wget -O '/content/drive/MyDrive/exper/large_dataset.zip' 'https://storage.googleapis.com/kaggle-competitions-data/kaggle-v2/52254/6863140/compressed/train_images.zip?GoogleAccessId=web-data@kaggle-161607.iam.gserviceaccount.com&Expires=1712717891&Signature=J3YlAImwlFNvchNDo%2FTw%2FXb8uvn7YcqwyDaAAt%2FoUHSrjqZ4TOno0dGGxpiDo8x%2B%2F1bV6fkqLSmIwx3Qf2QAODD%2Fzw8eWyeDs7%2F3PKxgoBSFa7GJSZVuYZhzSuzC5AkV5CqtvBlyEMU6yiD11%2BorIsEH6nmi1IqVGhWeHMey2PuPZTb3TO816udpk6t57WDv9mDW8R4E1snQU4kLX17HLRuE1HJxTL1uRy7US1GI0ntBArvyWz9OAQLRo2%2B8LCBFjPQUfU9iJ%2B8enEqomhI%2B5KNjIAptJLHWGfWtNLrbiEgeNDk%2BuMH3tt7hjSE9CBN%2BX%2BRF0RUfunfhcVaDFjXe1g%3D%3D&response-content-disposition=attachment%3B+filename%3Dtrain_images.zip' 
4-tried to make data chunks with kaggle notebook on kaggle itself, but it took alot of time to upload one chunk on kaggle as dataset.
5-tried to use gdown, same
import gdown

# URL of the dataset on Google Drive
url = 'https://storage.googleapis.com/kaggle-competitions-data/kaggle-v2/52254/6863140/compressed/train_images.zip?GoogleAccessId=web-data@kaggle-161607.iam.gserviceaccount.com&Expires=1712717891&Signature=J3YlAImwlFNvchNDo%2FTw%2FXb8uvn7YcqwyDaAAt%2FoUHSrjqZ4TOno0dGGxpiDo8x%2B%2F1bV6fkqLSmIwx3Qf2QAODD%2Fzw8eWyeDs7%2F3PKxgoBSFa7GJSZVuYZhzSuzC5AkV5CqtvBlyEMU6yiD11%2BorIsEH6nmi1IqVGhWeHMey2PuPZTb3TO816udpk6t57WDv9mDW8R4E1snQU4kLX17HLRuE1HJxTL1uRy7US1GI0ntBArvyWz9OAQLRo2%2B8LCBFjPQUfU9iJ%2B8enEqomhI%2B5KNjIAptJLHWGfWtNLrbiEgeNDk%2BuMH3tt7hjSE9CBN%2BX%2BRF0RUfunfhcVaDFjXe1g%3D%3D&response-content-disposition=attachment%3B+filename%3Dtrain_images.zip'

# Path in your Google Drive where you want to save the file
output = '/content/drive/MyDrive/exper/large_dataset.zip'

# Download the file
gdown.download(url, output, quiet=False)


6- and tried this, failed:
import requests
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from google.colab import auth
import io

# Authenticate Google Drive API
auth.authenticate_user()
drive_service = build('drive', 'v3')

# URL of the dataset you want to download
url = 'https://storage.googleapis.com/kaggle-competitions-data/kaggle-v2/52254/6863140/compressed/train_images.zip?GoogleAccessId=web-data@kaggle-161607.iam.gserviceaccount.com&Expires=1712717891&Signature=J3YlAImwlFNvchNDo%2FTw%2FXb8uvn7YcqwyDaAAt%2FoUHSrjqZ4TOno0dGGxpiDo8x%2B%2F1bV6fkqLSmIwx3Qf2QAODD%2Fzw8eWyeDs7%2F3PKxgoBSFa7GJSZVuYZhzSuzC5AkV5CqtvBlyEMU6yiD11%2BorIsEH6nmi1IqVGhWeHMey2PuPZTb3TO816udpk6t57WDv9mDW8R4E1snQU4kLX17HLRuE1HJxTL1uRy7US1GI0ntBArvyWz9OAQLRo2%2B8LCBFjPQUfU9iJ%2B8enEqomhI%2B5KNjIAptJLHWGfWtNLrbiEgeNDk%2BuMH3tt7hjSE9CBN%2BX%2BRF0RUfunfhcVaDFjXe1g%3D%3D&response-content-disposition=attachment%3B+filename%3Dtrain_images.zip'

# Path in your Google Drive where you want to save the file
output_path = '/content/drive/MyDrive/exper/big_dataset.zip'

# Download the file from the URL
response = requests.get(url)

# Write the downloaded content to Google Drive
file_metadata = {'name': 'big_dataset.zip'}
media = io.BytesIO(response.content)
file = drive_service.files().create(body=file_metadata, media_body=media, fields='id').execute()

# Move the file to the desired location in your Google Drive
drive_service.files().update(fileId=file.get('id'), addParents='1-Prja6blG04FwdcmNGDW9lnrKYgpJcGB').execute()


please help, I have nothing to do but buy Colab Pro Plus and that is NOT fair.
